# SQL Server database compare tool

Tags: sql-server, database

Does someone know of a good free SQL Server database compare tool? Something like what RedGate has.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[DBComparer](http://dbcomparer.com/) might be what You're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Never used, but it's in my bookmarks for when I need it, it's free and looks ok: [Open DBDdiff](http://opendbiff.codeplex.com/).
Let us know your conclusions if you try it !